# Plotting a white grayscale image in python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

This should be embarrassingly simple, but I'm missing something. The aim is to create and plot a white image in matplotlib. The code below should be close, but it plots a black image. What am I missing?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

height = 100
white = np.ones((height, height), dtype=np.float)
print white
plt.imshow(white, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, if the post below answers your question please accept it as the solution ... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
plt.imshow(white, cmap='gray',vmin=0,vmax=1)
```